# Wierd margin in jsfiddle

Tags: html, css, jsfiddle

Can anyone explain what I am missing here in this jsfiddle ... why are there margins between the images?

http://jsfiddle.net/XRBK8/

**Html**

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background:pink;
}
img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*why are there margins between the images?*

`Inline` and `inline-block` elements are affected by white-space and carriage returns in your HTML, if you delete the space you'll notice their border edges align:

http://jsfiddle.net/Adrift/XRBK8/1/

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to float the images:

```
img {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: left;
}
```